# display one of the images of a list of uploaded images

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, e-commerce

i'm working on a codeigniter based ecommerce website where for a product multiple images are uploaded. I havent set a field where the user can select to make one of the images as a default that displays large while having all other images as thumbs below it. What kind of query would i write to grab one of the images and display it as a default?

Answer (score 0):

Since i dont know your DB-structure, here is some pseudo-code:

```
SELECT img_src 
FROM product_images, product_info 
WHERE product_info.id = product_images.product_id
```

In the model you sort them in an array and in the view you do a foreach with:

```
if($i == 0): echo '<div class="big_img"><img src="' . $product_images[$i]['img_src'] . '" /></div>';
else: echo '<div class="thumb_img"><img src="' . $product_images[$i]['img_src'] . '" /></div>';
```